# How to query records number in a joint query?

Tags: mysql

for example,I have 2 tables student & report, "student" log student info,"report" log every student's school report,a student has more than one reports so report table has a foreign key "sid" referenced to student table,now I want to query every student's info and his report number,so how can I do the query in one query?  Currently I had to use two queries.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will work.

```
select t1.student_name,t1.student_id,group_concat(t2.report_number) as report_numbers
from student
left join report t2 ON t1.student_id=t2.sid
group by t1.student_name,t1.student_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```sql
select t1.student_name,t1.student_id,group_concat(t2.report_number) as report_numbers
from student
left join report t2 ON t1.student_id=t2.sid
group by t1.student_name,t1.student_id
```

i think it helpful

Comment: Yes,it works, I use below query string,thank you!


select t1.*,count(t2.sid) as report_nb from student left join report on student.id=report.sid group by student.id

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Your answer adds very little to the original question which is marked as duplicate.